# How to search for a particular string in a nested div class using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a custom javascript to fetch some data from a webpage. Basically I want to check if a particular page contains a string "125" . After looking up the source code of the webpage, I see that the container for the above string is a nested div class , something similar to-

```
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="tz-blog-wrapper-style-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="margin: 2% 0 0 0;" id="my_profile-right">
               <div class="live-top-right">
                    <div class="wid_2" style="float: right; color: #0961c7; font-weight: bold; font-size: 17px;" id="count_today">125</div>
                   ...
</div>
```

I can use  `.contains()` function, but the string "125" can be present at multiple places on the webpage.  I just want to check if its present in the above div class (see line 6 in the above code snippet). Its presence on rest of the page does not matter to me.

How should I proceed ?

Comment: what is preventing you only iterating through that specific class?

Comment: $("#count_today:contains(125)") or something along those lines

Comment: $(".wid_2:contains(125)") or something along those lines

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **RegExp** method of javascript and check if the result contains the *number* you want.

```
var content ='<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 125 col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1"><div class="tz-blog-wrapper-style-3"><div class="row"><div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="margin: 2% 0 0 0;" id="my_profile-right"><div class="live-top-right"><div class="wid_2" style="float: right; color: #0961c7; font-weight: bold; font-size: 17px;" id="count_today">125</div></div>';

var customRegEx = new RegExp('<div class="wid_2" .+>125<\/div>', 'i');
console.log(content.includes(content.match(customRegEx)));
```

Don't forget to replace the **content** variable with your own string variable.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can get this with...

```
var elem;

$('div').children().each(function(index) {
  if($(this).text() === '125') {
    elem = $(this);
  }
});

console.log(elem);

console.log('elem id: ', elem.attr('id'))

console.log('eleme innerHTML', elem.text());
```